# Kubernetes - Request CPU & Limit CPU issue

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod in kubernetes with the request CPU 100m and Limit cpu with 4000m.

The application spins up 500+ threads and it works fine. The application becomes unresponsive during heavy load and could be because of the thread limit issue.

**Question:-**

The number of threads are related to CPU's.

Since, the request CPU is 100m, Will there be any problem in the thread limitation, or, pod can still spin up more threads as the Limit is 4000m.

Comment: In addition to Jonas's answer, consider the official document and explanation about [requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since, the request CPU is 100m, Will there be any problem in the thread limitation, or, pod can still spin up more threads as the Limit is 4000m.

The CPU limitation is 4000m (4 cores), so it can use as many threads as it wants and use CPU utilization up to 4 cores.

The CPU request of 100m is almost only used for Pod scheduling, so your pod might end up on a node with few resources compared to your limitation, and might be evicted if there are few available CPU resources on the node.